# MySQL not using primary key as index

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I checked other questions with the same issue, But they seem not to have a primary key or the number of rows to examine is low which lets MySQL decides not to use an index.
In my case it is different, Joining with "dossiers" table adds 10 seconds for query to execute.
This is EXPLAIN result:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | statuts | const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | dossiers | ALL | PRIMARY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 92801 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | dt | ref | PRIMARY,dossierId,statutId | dossierId | 4 | btecma5_jaddad.dossiers.dossierId | 1 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | dtst | ref | dossierTribunalId,statutProcedureId,utilisateurId | dossierTribunalId | 4 | btecma5_jaddad.dt.dossierTribunalId | 4 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sp | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | btecma5_jaddad.dtst.statutProcedureId | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | utilisateurs | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | btecma5_jaddad.dtst.utilisateurId | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | dtt | ref | dossierTribunalId | dossierTribunalId | 4 | btecma5_jaddad.dt.dossierTribunalId | 6 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | dttl | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | btecma5_jaddad.dtt.dossierTribunalTransfertLotId | 1 | Using where |

And this the query: ( dossiers.estSoumis is not indexed but it doesn't make much difference )

```sql
SELECT 
      dt.utilisateurId dossierPhysiqueUtilisateurId,
      COUNT(dttl.dossierTribunalTransfertLotId) totalTransferts,
      traceDate dateSoumission,
      dtst.utilisateurId creationUtilisateurId,
      CONCAT(utilisateurs.prenom,' ',utilisateurs.nom) nomAgent 
 FROM dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces dtst
 JOIN dossiers_tribunaux dt USING(dossierTribunalId)
 LEFT JOIN dossiers_tribunaux_transferts dtt
        ON(dt.dossierTribunalId = dtt.dossierTribunalId)
 LEFT JOIN dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots dttl
        ON(dttl.dossierTribunalTransfertLotId = dtt.dossierTribunalTransfertLotId
           AND dttl.statut = 1)
 JOIN dossiers dossiers USING(dossierId)
 JOIN utilisateurs utilisateurs
        ON(utilisateurs.utilisateurId = dtst.utilisateurId)
 JOIN statuts_procedures sp USING(statutProcedureId)
 JOIN statuts statuts ON(statuts.statutId = sp.statutId)
WHERE statuts.statutId = 1 
  AND dt.statutId != 211 
  AND dossiers.estSoumis = 1 
  AND dtst.utilisateurId IN(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 62, 63) 
GROUP BY dt.dossierTribunalId;
```

EDIT: Tables structure and indexes added:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `dossiers`
--

CREATE TABLE `dossiers` (
  `dossierId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `numeroDossier` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `typeDossier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1:masse;2:grand',
  `clientId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreation` datetime NOT NULL,
  `creationUtilisateurId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `estSoumis` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dateSoumission` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `anneeDossier` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `estArreter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '1:provisoire,2:definitif',
  `arretDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `arretUtilisateurId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `arretAnnulationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `arretAnnulationUtilisateurId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `piecesClientsScan` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0:pas encore;1:scannés',
  `piecesClientsScanDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lotFacturationId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `dossiers_tribunaux`
--

CREATE TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux` (
  `dossierTribunalId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dossierTribunalParentId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numeroTribunalSequence` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numeroTribunalCodeProcedure` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `numeroTribunalAnnee` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `procedureId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dossierId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `statutId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces`
--

CREATE TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces` (
  `dossierTribunalStatutTraceId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dossierTribunalId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `statutProcedureId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `traceDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `utilisateurId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dossierActionId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `besoinScan` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `estScanne` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `codeOperationScan` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estExcluOperationScan` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `exclusionOperationScanUtilisateurId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exclusionOperationScanDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `extraCommentaire` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `extraCommentaireDerniereMaj` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `statutAffichable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `crediteurId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crediteurDerniereMaj` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estIgnoreAudit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts`
--

CREATE TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts` (
  `dossierTribunalTransfertId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dossierTribunalTransfertLotId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dossierTribunalId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots`
--

CREATE TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots` (
  `dossierTribunalTransfertLotId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `deUtilisateurId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aUtilisateurId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateTransfert` datetime NOT NULL,
  `statut` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0:en attente de validation;1: validé',
  `dateValidation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `numeroLot` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `anneeLot` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `orderType` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1:lotId;2:numeroDossier',
  `validationUtilisateurId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Pour diagnotiquer un probleme'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `statuts`
--

CREATE TABLE `statuts` (
  `statutId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `intituleStatut` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `intituleStatutParent` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ordreAffichage` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `intituleStatutArabe` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `informationsComplementaires` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `labelCouleur` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'info',
  `typeStatut` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1:Action à faire;2: Réponse tribunal',
  `estImportable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `majStatutsId` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `estRepetable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `statuts_procedures`
--

CREATE TABLE `statuts_procedures` (
  `statutProcedureId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `statutId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `procedureId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `intituleAction` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreJoursRetard` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreJoursRetardAlert` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `afficherTableauBord` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `utilisateurs`
--

CREATE TABLE `utilisateurs` (
  `utilisateurId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `motPasse` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `peutLierFacture` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `dossiers`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dossierId`),
  ADD KEY `creationUtilisateurId` (`creationUtilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `arretUtilisateurId` (`arretUtilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `arretAnnulationUtilisateurId` (`arretAnnulationUtilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `clientId` (`clientId`),
  ADD KEY `numeroDossier` (`numeroDossier`);

--
-- Indexes for table `dossiers_tribunaux`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dossierTribunalId`),
  ADD KEY `procedureId` (`procedureId`),
  ADD KEY `dossierId` (`dossierId`),
  ADD KEY `banqueId` (`banqueId`),
  ADD KEY `employeurId` (`employeurId`),
  ADD KEY `statutId` (`statutId`),
  ADD KEY `suiviId` (`suiviId`),
  ADD KEY `utilisateurId` (`utilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `lotFacturationId` (`lotFacturationId`);
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `contratsId` (`contratsId`);
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `adversairesId` (`adversairesId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dossierTribunalStatutTraceId`),
  ADD KEY `dossierTribunalId` (`dossierTribunalId`),
  ADD KEY `statutProcedureId` (`statutProcedureId`),
  ADD KEY `dossierActionId` (`dossierActionId`),
  ADD KEY `utilisateurId` (`utilisateurId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dossierTribunalTransfertId`),
  ADD KEY `dossierTribunalTransfertLotId` (`dossierTribunalTransfertLotId`),
  ADD KEY `dossierTribunalId` (`dossierTribunalId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dossierTribunalTransfertLotId`),
  ADD KEY `deUtilisateurId` (`deUtilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `aUtilisateurId` (`aUtilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `validationUtilisateurId` (`validationUtilisateurId`),
  ADD KEY `dossiers_transfert_idx_autilisateurid_dossiertribunal` (`aUtilisateurId`,`dossierTribunalTransfertLotId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `statuts`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`statutId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `statuts_procedures`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuts_procedures`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`statutProcedureId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `utilisateurs`
--
ALTER TABLE `utilisateurs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`utilisateurId`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dossiers`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers`
  MODIFY `dossierId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dossiers_tribunaux`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux`
  MODIFY `dossierTribunalId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_statuts_traces`
  MODIFY `dossierTribunalStatutTraceId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts`
  MODIFY `dossierTribunalTransfertId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots`
--
ALTER TABLE `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots`
  MODIFY `dossierTribunalTransfertLotId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `statuts`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuts`
  MODIFY `statutId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `statuts_procedures`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuts_procedures`
  MODIFY `statutProcedureId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `utilisateurs`
--
ALTER TABLE `utilisateurs`
  MODIFY `utilisateurId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see *all* relevant table definitions and index definitions, as well as the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Try explicitly defining your join conditions using ON rather than USING

Comment: An index would only be used if using it significantly reduces the number of records to be scanned.  If using the 4 conditions in the WHERE criteria, finally, from the dossiers table, most of the dossier_ids end up being looked at so that the sequential search in dossiers table could be faster as compared to going through the index and finally going through most of the dossiers records, then the index might not be used.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you, I added tables structures, EXPLAIN output is already attached.

Comment: @Ishan I'm afraid it's not the case as the number of rows to scan is too high, And removing the join with the "dossiers" table reduces 9 seconds and runs it in less than a second.

Comment: @NickW  Already tried it on the join with "dossiers" table which causes the slow execution, And it literally changed nothing.

Comment: @user1191247 I tried to post it as code and it's not working, I'm sorry about the images

Comment: @user1191247 It seems that the selection of code after pasting works, Thank you.

Comment: @user1191247 okey for EXPLAIN remark, But for tables structures, It seemes like it's the same format ?!

Comment: @user1191247 for the banqueId, I had to remove some columns that are irrelevant to the query, but it surely exists in the table, Concerning the other parts of the query, they are not causing any delay in the execution so they are irrelevant in this case, the only thing that’s making it slow is the joins and I can’t figure out what other indexes I might have to create to make it run faster

Comment: You should read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) to get a better understanding of non-deterministic queries and their problems. You should read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-when-to-use-utf8mb3-over-utf8mb4/) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) WRT your use of utf8mb3. You have a potential CROSS JOIN issue with dtst and dtt/dttl. As you are only referencing two columns from `dossiers`, there are only four possible index combinations. Have you tried them?

Comment: @user1191247 I will read about the group by, use of utfmb3 … for the potential CROSS JOIN issue can you give me more details ? And no I didnt try any combinations of indexes except the PKs and FKs , what are these possible combinations please ?

Comment: @user1191247 Can you tell me you knew I'm using utf8mb3 ? Cuz I checked and found utf8mb4.

Comment: All your CREATE TABLE statements have utf8 which is aliased to utf8mb3.

Comment: @user1191247 What if I'm using a recent mysql version ? doesn't it take utf8mb4 as default ? becaue after executing "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';" it's only showing values with utf8mb4

Comment: The default charset for MySQL 8 is `utf8mb4` but if your CREATE TABLE statements have `CHARSET=utf8` then they will be created with charset `utf8mb3`. You can check current tables/columns with `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'btecma5_jaddad' AND CHARACTER_SET_NAME IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why the PK *may* not be used.  But first, let's add some 'composite' indexes that are likely to help with performance:

```
dt:  INDEX(statutId, dossierTribunalId,  utilisateurId, dossierId)
dtst:  INDEX(utilisateurId, dossierTribunalId,  statutProcedureId)
    and DROP  KEY `utilisateurId`
dtt:  INDEX(dossierTribunalId,  dossierTribunalTransfertLotId)
    and DROP  KEY `dossierTribunalId`
dossiers:  INDEX(estSoumis, dossierId)
```

(Many of those are also "covering", as indicated by "Using index".)

If `estSoumis` is not selective enough, my recommendation for `dossiers` may not help much.

`dossiers_tribunaux_transferts` is structured like a many-to-many mapping table.  If that is its intent, then drop the surrogate id and add a 2-column PK and a 2-column `INDEX` in the opposite order.  See [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: @user1191247 - Thanks.  I added more detail in that direction.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I tried all four suggested indexes and tried to see the difference each one does, And it seems that "dtt" index is the only one that reduced time from 9s to 7s, "dossiers" recommandation didn't make much difference but it decreased number of rows to scan almost to half, I will give the last suggestion a try on a test environement. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these 2 compound indices:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_dossierTribunalTransfertLotId_statut ON dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots(dossierTribunalTransfertLotId, statut);
CREATE INDEX idx_dossierId_estSoumis ON dossiers(dossierId, estSoumis);
```

`dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots(dossierTribunalTransfertLotId, statut)` *might* help speed up the LEFT JOIN between `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts` and `dossiers_tribunaux_transferts_lots`, as well as the filtering condition `dttl.statut = 1` in the ON clause.

`dossiers(dossierId, estSoumis)` *might* help speed up the JOIN between `dossiers_tribunaux` and `dossiers`, as well as the filtering condition `dossiers.estSoumis = 1` in the WHERE clause.

*edit: I note you may have already tried the reverse order of the columns and as `estSoumis` is tinyint that order may perform better. I had this answer sitting in edit without posting and left it overnight by mistake, then posted and saw the other answer.*